# Changing height of a div element using javascript or jquery but it must change slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have set a background in a div element and i want to increase the height of that div tag when I click on an anchor tag. But i want the height to be increased slowly.

Answer (score 9):

You can change the `duration` of the animation:

```
$('#element').animate({
    height: '200px'
}, {
    duration: 2000  // 2 seconds
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t5VYa/**

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

```
$('#selector').animate({
    height: '500px'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

where 5000 is the duration in milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Do you think animation? JQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at jQuery animation. http://api.jquery.com/animate/ I think it might do what you want to do. It has a set of sample to manipulate the various aspects of element