# how to increase height of a div slowly using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a webpage with black background color, and it should have a div of red color, and when we hover on that red div the height of the div should increase slowly to the top of the page and when you remove your mouse from the div the height should decrease with the same speed it increased.
below is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>animate</title>
<script>

    function changeHeight() {
$('#first').animate({height:500},500);
}

</script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black">
<div id="first" style="background-color: red; width: 10%; height: 50px" onMouseOver="changeHeight();"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, the event corresponding with `onmouseover` is `onmouseout`. Give that a whirl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing height of a div element using javascript or jquery but it must change slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712602/changing-height-of-a-div-element-using-javascript-or-jquery-but-it-must-change-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha.

```css
html,body
{
   padding: 0;
   background: black;
}
div
{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}
div:hover
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

If you want to pretend to use JavaScript because the exercise demands it:

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");
div.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => div.classList.add("hover"));
div.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => div.classList.remove("hover"));
```

```css
html,body
{
   padding: 0;
   background: black;
}
div
{
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  transition: all linear 5s;
}
div.hover
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it had any kind of explanation instead of just Haha.

Comment: But it would be less humorous to me :) I'll hide the explanation here: No Javascript required, use the tools that work best for the problem. In this case: CSS transitions.

Comment: @AtifAli: Sure :)

Comment: @H.B. bro it would be a great help if you could just give a heading that what part is for which tag, for example which code is inside body and which code is in style tag.

Comment: @AtifAli: HTML: `<div></div>`, all the rest is CSS. If you cannot tell, then you really should learn some basics first.

Comment: actually i was asking about the javascript trick you did, is it going to be in the script tag @H.B.

Comment: @AtifAli: Yes, it is.

Comment: @H.B.
this is not working when i run it after putting it in dreamweaver.